# How to Pivot Columns in Pyspark by Grouping other Columns?

Tags: python, sql, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Suppose I have a PySpark DataFrame with columns **date**, **item_id**, **item_type**, and **item_vol**. Below is the sample input:

[image]

And I am trying to get the output as below:
[image]

Here, each item_id can have multiple item_types and item_vols. I want to transform this DataFrame into a wide format where each row represents a unique combination of date and item_id, and columns **item_type_X** and **item_vol_X** represent the Xth item type and item volume for that item ID, respectively. If an item ID has fewer than X item types or item volumes, the corresponding columns should be filled with null. Item **item_type_X** and **item_vol_X** have a limit of 5. Which becomes **item_type_5** and **item_vol_5**

I was using the below code.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType, IntegerType, DateType
from pyspark.sql.functions import when

from pyspark.sql.functions import col, collect_list
# create a SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("example").getOrCreate()

# create the schema for the DataFrame
schema = StructType([
    StructField("date", StringType(), True),
    StructField("item_id", StringType(), True),
    StructField("item_type", StringType(), True),
    StructField("item_vol", IntegerType(), True)
])

# create the DataFrame
data = [
    ('2019-01-01', 'item3', 'aa', 1),
    ('2019-01-01', 'item3', 'bb', 2),
    ('2019-01-01', 'item67', 'cc', 4),
    ('2019-01-01', 'item67', 'dd', None),
    ('2019-01-01', 'item68', 'gas', 9),
]

new_df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema).orderBy("date", "item_id", "item_type", "item_vol")

# show the DataFrame
new_df.show()


# group by date and item_id and collect lists of item_type and item_vol
ordered_df = new_df\
                    .groupBy("date", "item_id") \
                    .agg(collect_list("item_type").alias("item_type_list"),
                         collect_list(when(col("item_vol").isNull(), "null").otherwise(col("item_vol"))).alias("item_vol_list"))
ordered_df.show(5, False)
from pyspark.sql.functions import split, col

num_cols = 5
pivot_cols = []
for i in range(num_cols):
    item_type_expr = col("item_type_list").getItem(i).alias(f"item_type_{i+1}")
    item_vol_expr = col("item_vol_list").getItem(i).alias(f"item_vol_{i+1}")
    pivot_cols.extend([item_type_expr, item_vol_expr])

# split the "item_type_list" and "item_vol_list" columns and store each item in different columns
split_df = ordered_df.select("date", "item_id",
                             *pivot_cols
                             )

# show the resulting DataFrame
split_df.show(10, False)
```

However, using collect_list does not retain the order of the rows. I wanted to keep **item_type** in ascending order. But using collect_list in groupBy sometimes messes up the order of the column. I mean like below:
[image]

It would be appreciated, if someone could help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

#### Code

```
# Define a window spec
W = Window.partitionBy('date', 'item_id').orderBy('item_type')

# Assign sequential numbers to uniquely identify rows per date and item_id
# such that row numbers are ordered by ascending order of item_type  
new_df = new_df.withColumn('col', F.row_number().over(W))

# groupby and reshape with pivot 
result = (
    new_df
    .groupBy('date', 'item_id')
    .pivot('col')
    .agg(F.first('item_type').alias('item_type'), 
         F.first('item_vol').alias('item_vol') )
)

# Rename and fill the missing columns with null
for i in range(1, 6):
    if f'{i}_item_type' in result.columns:
        result = result.withColumnRenamed(f'{i}_item_type', f'item_type_{i}')
        result = result.withColumnRenamed(f'{i}_item_vol', f'item_vol_{i}')
    else:
        result = result.withColumn(f'item_type_{i}', F.lit(None))
        result = result.withColumn(f'item_vol_{i}', F.lit(None))
```

#### Result

```
+----------+-------+-----------+----------+-----------+----------+-----------+----------+-----------+----------+-----------+----------+
|      date|item_id|item_type_1|item_vol_1|item_type_2|item_vol_2|item_type_3|item_vol_3|item_type_4|item_vol_4|item_type_5|item_vol_5|
+----------+-------+-----------+----------+-----------+----------+-----------+----------+-----------+----------+-----------+----------+
|2019-01-01|  item3|         aa|         1|         bb|         2|       null|      null|       null|      null|       null|      null|
|2019-01-01| item67|         cc|         4|         dd|      null|       null|      null|       null|      null|       null|      null|
|2019-01-01| item68|        gas|         9|       null|      null|       null|      null|       null|      null|       null|      null|
+----------+-------+-----------+----------+-----------+----------+-----------+----------+-----------+----------+-----------+----------+
```